# Find min,max labels in RDD[LabeledPoint] Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD[LabeledPoint] and I want to find the min and the max of the labels and also apply some transformations, such as subtracting from all of them the number 5. The problem is I have tried various ways to get to the labels, but nothing works correctly.

How can I access only the labels and only the features of the RDD? Is there a way to get them as a List[Double] and List[Vector] for example?

I cannot go to dataframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after playing around with the map function, i came up with this solution

```
val labels = rdd.map(x=> x.label)
val min = labels.min
val max = labels.max
```

If you want to make changes to the labels, once again you can use the map function

```
rdd.map(x=> x.label - 5)
```

This way you can play around with the label part of a RDD[LabeledPoint].

After the comments of Cyril below, I decided to also add the command that lets you keep your RDD and change only the label however you want.

```
val newRdd = rdd.map(x => x.copy(x.label -5))
```

Comment: You should be aware of when an action/transformation is actually executed on `RDD`s to avoid computing twice the same thing, or risking a `MemoryOverflow`. In your case, the transformation `x => x.label` will be executed twice on your collection (once for `min` and once for `max`).

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet I have a question that came up just now. I want to have the same RDD with my labels changed with the substraction I made. How do I do that? Cause if i just go and do val rdd = rdd.map(x => x.label -5) I'll only have the labels, not the whole Rdd

Comment: you could just do `rdd.map(x => x.copy(label = x.label - 5))`

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet this doesnt change the label at all. I get the same rdd.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet nevermind, I had a typo, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create DataFrames from an existing RDD with a SparkSession.For DataFrame you can operate it anyway.

Comment: dataframes are something I cant use, I should have written it above. Will edit it now.

Comment: As RDD is immutable,it's impossible for you to change the labels on the same RDD.To avoid recomputing,you can cache the RDD before.